# Form Validation w/Javascript - Not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following form, done with HTML and Javascript validation.

```
var submitOK=true;
function validate(){
    submitOK=true;
    checkName();
    checkSurname();
checkCourse();
checkDate();
checkEmail();


   if(submitOK == false) { 
  return false;}
}

function checkName() {
     var name = document.getElementById("name");
  if(myform.name.value.length==0)
  {
    document.getElementById("checkname").innerHTML="Please, enter a valid name";
    submitOK=false;
  }
  }
```

(COMPLETE CODE IN HERE)
http://jsfiddle.net/unkok6or/

The fields Course, Date, Name, Surname and Email have to be required. I don't know why my code is wrong and how to fix it.

-What I would like, is an error message to appear if one of the fields is not complete. Now the form runs and works even if one of them is not completed.

-The email with the correct format (without Regex).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Take a look: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code a little bit. This worked for me.  The key thing to remember that your submit function must return a true to submit or false to stop the submit.

```
var submitOK=true;

function validate(){
    submitOK=true;
    checkName();
    checkSurname();
    checkCourse();
    checkDate();
    checkEmail();


    return submitOK;
}

function checkName() {
    if( document.getElementById("name").value.length==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("checkname").innerHTML="Please, enter a valid name";
        submitOK=false;
    }
}

function checkSurname() {

    if(document.getElementById("surname").value.length==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("checksurname").innerHTML="Please, enter a valid surname";
        submitOK=false;
    }
}

function checkEmail() {
    if(document.getElementById("email").value.length==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("checkemail").innerHTML="Please, enter an email";
        submitOK=false;
    }
}   


function checkCourse() {

    if(document.getElementById("course").selectedIndex < 1 ) {
        document.getElementById("checkcourse").innerHTML="Please, select a course";
        submitOK=false;
    }
} 

function checkDate() {

    if(document.getElementById("date").selectedIndex < 1) {
        document.getElementById("checkdate").innerHTML="Please, select a date";
        submitOK=false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a regular expression, tons of examples out there. Use regex, javascript and email in your search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true when your validation passes so change

```
if(submitOK == false) { 
  return false;}
```

to

```
 return submitOk;
```

Comment: So, I select options from the "Course" and "Date" drop down, and the error messages appear for the rest of the fields, but the page refreshes too quick to read. The same if some of the fields are filled, the messages appear, but the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make sure all the fields are filled, why don't you use required keyword on ur input types. 
And for drop down you can disable the select option that way you don't need to check if the user has selected the default value.

Comment: Because I'm forced to do it with Javascript.
The required keyword is HTML5, isn't it?